# Prove not mutually independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are throwing two dice.

Let $A$ be the event that the first die is odd.
$B$ be the event that second die is odd.
$C$ be the event that sum of outcomes of two dice is odd.

Show that those three events are not mutually independent?

My approach is that im showing $A,B$ are independent, $B,C$ are independent, $A, C$ are independent but I cannot come to the conclusion that those three are mutually independent. Am I correct?

Comment: "total point of 2 dice", i.e. the sum of outcomes of both dice?

Comment: yes i just edited the sentence

Answer (score 2):

Note that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=0$, while $P(A)P(B)P(C)=\frac18$.

Comment: I've already thought about your approach that I will write: (^: intersect) P[A ^ B ^ C] = P[A].P[B].P[C] . But LHS = 0 and RHS = 1/8, so we cannot say they are mutually independent. Is it enough to say that? Thought we would need more proofs here ...

Comment: $A$ an $B$ are independent, as are $B$ and $C$, as are $A$ and $C$. But from your problem as written, you were not asked to show any of these things.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability that $A$, $B$, and $C$ simultaneously occur?  What are the individual probabilities of $A$, $B$, and $C$?  Why am I asking these two questions? [Remember to look up the definition of what it means for a collection of random variables to be independent.]

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to notice $P(C) >P(C|AB)=0$